# Drop the leading zero using number_with_precision

Tags: ruby-on-rails, number-formatting

I have an app that tracks a player's baseball stats.  I want it to show Batting Average without the leading zero (**.333** instead of **0.333**).  I've been trying number_with_precision with no luck.

Here is the line from my View:

```
<%= number_with_precision(@player.batting_average, :precision => 3, 
    :significant => true, :strip_insignificant_zeros => true) %>
```

Here is the code from the Model:

```
def batting_average
  self.hits / self.at_bats.to_f
end
```

Based on the [number_with_precision](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_with_precision) Rails 3.1.3 documentation, :strip_insignificant_zeros only applies to zeros after the decimal and :significant doesn't affect the decimals.  Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a ton of ways to do this, but the main thing to recognize is that you are dealing with a **float** and will need to convert it over to a string to use things like `gsub` and `[]`.

Here are some ideas:

```
def to_ba
  self.to_s[1..-1]
end
```

or with `gsub`

```
def to_ba
  self.to_s.gsub(/^0+/, '')
end
```

or if you want to get crazy (and this is more for fun than anything else):

```
def to_ba
  self.to_s.reverse.chop.reverse
end
```

These are all helper methods that could be added on the end of your value like this:

```
number_with_precision( stuff ).to_ba
```

or you could just attach any of these methods to the end of your call like this:

```
number_with_precision( stuff ).to_s[1..-1]
```

**But I would use the helper** if you plan to put batting averages all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

No. That's the correct behavior. You could write a helper that does it the right way or just add `gsub(/^0+/,'')`.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/136990

```
def trim_lead(n)
    self.gsub!(/^#{n}+/,'')
end
```